# Why is `this` different when opening index.html in the browser as opposed to serving index.html with a node server?

Tags: javascript

I have an index.html file, referencing a javascript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>asd</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In my ***index.js***

```
function init() {
    // always prints the window-object
    console.log("init this:", this);
}
var testFunc = () => {
    // this = {} when served
    // this = window when opened directly in browser
    console.log("testFunc this:", this);
}
// prints the window-object when opening index.html
// prints {} when using a server
console.log("this:", this);
init();
testFunc();
```

Why does opening the index.html file directly in the browser (url: file:///index.html) making `this` the `window`-object all the time, whilst serving the index.html file with a server (url: http://localhost:1234/) sometimes gives me `{}`, and sometimes `window`?

I expected `testFunc()` to print `{}`, and I expected to get the `window` elsewhere. Why is it different?

Note:  I used [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) to serve my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log("this:", this);
```

*this*, in a global execution context, references the global object.

```
init();
```

Since *this* is not set in the call and the code is not in strict mode, within the *init* function it will reference the global object (in strict mode, it would have the value *undefined*).

```
testFunc();
```

Since *testFunc* is an arrow function, its *this* is adopted from its enclosing scope, which is global so again the global object.

In browsers, the [*window* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is an alias for the global object and has additional properties (e.g. *escape*, *unescape*) and implements the window interface.

How a console choses to represent an object when displaying it in the console is up to the implementation.

Comment: I did not know `'use strict'` made such a difference. And thanks for a thorough explanation

Answer (score 1):

`this`, in the global scope, will always refer to the Global Object. 
In each environment the Global Object is different.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. Regardless, I thought using the syntax `var testFunc = () => { console.log(this); }` would create this = {}, but it does not when opening index.html in the browser, why is that?

Comment: It does not give me `undefined`. It gives me `window`. Using the arrow function and a normal function both gives me the window-object when opening the index.html directly in the browser.

Comment: You  are right, I was confusing irrelevant things.
Do you have another question?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the global object in the current environment of the code execution, so it is normal that it'll be different each time.

Comment: That is somewhat simplistic, *this* might reference the global object, but often does not.